# How do I edit an RSS feed URL in Outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, rss

How do I edit an RSS feed URL in Outlook 2007?

I tried figuring out on my own for some time, but I wasn't able to find a way.

**NOTE:** I was able to change/modify all other properties, like *Feed Name, Delivery Location, Downloads* and *Update Limit*, though, `except` *Feed URL* from **Tools** -> **Account Settings** -> **RSS Feeds** -> **Change...**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a convenient way to do it. It might be easiest to add a new feed with the address you want. Then point that feed to the folder you were using previously.

Comment: This could be a *workaround*.  But, I'm surprised there is `no easy way` to edit/modify existing Feed URL directly.

Comment: I was surprised too. But in a way it makes sense as changing the URL essentially changes the feed entirely. RSS is based on the URL more than anything. As simple as it is to add a feed, they probably just let that be it.

Comment: Agreed, but there are cases (mine too) where the Feed provider itself just changing the URL path *alone* but the feed content remains the same.  BTW, thanks for your comment.