# How to change the location of a feed?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, rss

I use Outlook 2010 to keep track of a couple of (company-internal) RSS feeds, but they've been moved to a different location (basically, from `http://` to `https://`)

Is there a way to change the RSS source/"location" in Outlook? I've been googling around and I haven't found a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not. This is very similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/427834/97028), but a different version. The answer is the same.

Going to **`File > Info > Account Settings > RSS Feeds Tab`** the only choices to `change` are to modify the folder name, location and download options.

It would be less hassle to add a new feed with the updated address than to find a way to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, the way I solved it was to create a new feed with the new address/URL and to move the existing elements from the old feed into the new one. That said, I believe this is a "bug" in Outlook...

Thanks for the confirmation, though.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, if you have access to a programming environment, I've written a simple program to do this for my own needs.

The source code is here:
https://github.com/mcs-sss/SolSoft.Rss.RssManager

I'm working on setting up a page for someone to just save and run it.